# Is there an aggregate function in mysql that just picks any value from a series?

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a program to analyze stock prices. I have two MySQL tables loaded with dummy data as shown below.

```
mysql> select * from stock;
+----+--------+
| id | symbol |
+----+--------+
|  1 | A      |
|  2 | B      |
|  3 | C      |
|  4 | D      |
|  5 | E      |
|  6 | F      |
+----+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from stockhistory;
+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | trading_date | close     |
+----+--------------+-----------+
|  1 | 2018-01-01   | 200.00000 |
|  2 | 2018-01-02   | 150.00000 |
|  3 | 2018-01-03   | 120.00000 |
| 10 | 2018-04-28   | 105.00000 |
| 18 | 2018-05-02   | 105.00000 |
|  4 | 2018-05-03   | 105.00000 |
|  9 | 2017-05-02   | 400.00000 |
|  5 | 2017-11-11   | 200.00000 |
|  6 | 2017-11-12   | 300.00000 |
|  7 | 2017-11-13   | 400.00000 |
|  8 | 2017-11-14   | 500.00000 |
| 11 | 2018-04-28   | 105.00000 |
| 12 | 2018-04-29   | 106.00000 |
| 13 | 2018-04-30   | 107.00000 |
| 14 | 2018-05-01   | 108.00000 |
| 15 | 2018-05-02   | 109.00000 |
| 16 | 2018-05-03   | 110.00000 |
| 17 | 2018-05-04   |  90.00000 |
+----+--------------+-----------+
18 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I want to find all the stocks that made a yearly low within the past week. But to make this question more straightforward, assume that I want to see all the stocks whose lowest closing price since `'2017-05-04'` occurred on or after `'2018-04-30'`.

This is the query that does it:

```
mysql> select
    ->     s.symbol,
    ->     min(sh.trading_date),
    ->     min(low_table.low)
    -> from
    ->     (
    ->         select
    ->             stock_id,
    ->             min(close) as low
    ->         from
    ->             stocks_stockhistory
    ->         where
    ->             trading_date >= '2017-05-04'
    ->         group by
    ->             stock_id
    ->     ) as low_table,
    ->     stocks_stockhistory as sh,
    ->     stocks_stock as s
    -> where
    ->     sh.stock_id = low_table.stock_id
    ->     and sh.stock_id = s.id
    ->     and sh.close = low_table.low
    ->     and sh.trading_date >= '2018-04-30'
    -> group by
    ->     s.symbol
    -> order by
    ->     s.symbol asc;
+--------+----------------------+--------------------+
| symbol | min(sh.trading_date) | min(low_table.low) |
+--------+----------------------+--------------------+
| A      | 2018-05-02           |          105.00000 |
| C      | 2018-05-04           |           90.00000 |
+--------+----------------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

My question is about the select-clause of this SQL query.

I want to de-dupe rows for stocks that hit their low more than once since `2018-04-30`.

- To de-dupe the `s.symbol` field, I group by it.
- To de-dupe the `sh.trading_date` field, I do a `min()` in it. But I don't care if it is the minimum value. Any sh.trading_date value will do. Is there an aggregate function I can use instead of min() to pick any value? It seems wasteful to calculate the min if I don't need it.
- To de-dupe the `low_table.low` Field, I do a `min()` in it. But I don't care if it is the minimum value. **In fact, all the values are the same.** Is there an aggregate function I can use instead of min() to pick any value?

Comment: I would say that if you don't care, then this is symptomatic of deeper flaws in your design. You *should* care

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  the values in `low_table.low` are all the same, you can just remove the aggregation function on that field. The `GROUP BY` will then select an arbitrary value for it, but since they are all the same it won't matter.
Note that you will need to `low_table.low` to your `GROUP BY` clause.

Since the values in `sh.trading_date` can differ, you will need to keep an aggregation function on that field. If you didn't you would have to add it to the `GROUP BY` clause, which would cause extra lines in the output. As long as you have to use one, `MIN` is probably as efficient as any of them.

Comment: The GROUP BY does not pick values at random from the group. It depends on the storage engine and the index the rows are read from, but in most cases the value will be predictable. "Arbitrary" is not the same as "random."

Comment: @BillKarwin to the end user the effect of "in most cases predictable" and "random" is the same. However you are correct and I've updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Random would mean it is likely to pick a different result each time you run the same query. In fact, MySQL will probably pick the same result each time you run the query. That would surprise me if any user thinks these behaviors are the same.

Comment: @BillKarwin I edited my comment (a bit too slowly) but your wording is better and I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: No, this solution doesn't seem to work: https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/56c88363209d5bb11b0653d7fda6b2fa

Comment: As I mention in the answer you need to add those two columns to the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: @Nick, Oops! Sorry for my previous oversight! I corrected that error, but it is still not working correctly: https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/7b1eb8bd4f5b6217cc6aa516bbc6ec16

Comment: Hi, sorry I only tested the solution on the sample data in your question which didn't show that issue. You will need to keep the aggregation function on sh.trading_date otherwise you will have the problem of the group by creating extra lines. However you should still be able to group by `low_table.low` since all those values are the same. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: That's great. Glad to be of help.